# Azure IoT Edge message exchange scenarios

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I have a couple of questions regarding IoT Edge internals:

- Does C2D messaging work in transparent gateway scenario (send C2D messages to leaf devices through IoT Hub directly)?
- Does Fileupload work in transparent gateway scenario (leaf devices use Fileupload API in Device SDK through IoT Edge transparently)?
- When using Direct Methods between modules with edge device being online, will edgeHub handle it locally or does it go through IoT Hub?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does C2D messaging work in transparent gateway scenario (send C2D
>   messages to leaf devices through IoT Hub directly)?

I assume you mean async C2D messages: Yes, those work from the IoT Hub to leaf devices.

> Does Fileupload work in transparent gateway scenario (leaf devices use
>   Fileupload API in Device SDK through IoT Edge transparently)?

Yes, file upload works. However, the actual upload does not go through the Edge Device. The leaf device would need to have direct network access to the blob storage account in Azure.

> When using Direct Methods between modules with edge device being
>   online, will edgeHub handle it locally or does it go through IoT Hub?

It stays on the EdgeHub and does not traverse through IoT Hub.